# Magnitude of possible $66$-th idoneal number

Tags: number-theory, reference-request

Here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idoneal_number

it is mentioned that $65$ idoneal numbers are known and there is at most **two** additional idoneal number (probably the list is complete)

> Assuming that there is a $66$-th idoneal number, is anything known about the magnitude this number can have ?

Comment: Yes. Very, very, very big.

Comment: Tbh, I'm of the camp that believes the generalized Riemann Hypothesis probably holds, so I don't think there is one. But if its there, that would be $\textbf{gigantic}$ news because of its implications on the hypothesis.

Comment: @RushabhMehta Isn't the generalized Riemann Hypothesis a much stronger statement than the Riemann Hypothesis ? Maybe, I am wrong.

Comment: Yea it is, but even disproving the stronger version of the hypothesis would be pretty remarkable.

Comment: @WillJagy Do you have a reference for the best known lower bound ?

Comment: d = 2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17 * 19 * 23 * 29 * 31 =  200560490130 approx 2 * 10^11    http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa22/aa2221.pdf

Comment: @WillJagy Thank you!